Can the expression $\frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}Bx}$ be re-written in the form $\frac{x^{T}B^{-1}Ax}{x^{T}x}$?
I am studying Linear Discriminant Analysis. In the course of optimizing the scatter between/scatter within ratio, we optimize an expression of the form $\frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}Bx}$. At the end of the day I know that ratio is maximized when x is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $B^{-1}A$. However, I want to reconcile this with some other facts I know regarding expressions of this form. Namely:
1.) Expressions of the form $\frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}Bx}$ can be written as $\frac{x^{T}Gx}{x^{T}x}$ for some matrix G.
2.) When $\left|x^{T}x\right|=1$ optimizing $\frac{x^{T}Gx}{x^{T}x}$ is equivalent to optimizing $x^{T}Gx$. Again, this occurs when x is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of G
So, it seems like to me, given facts 1 & 2,  that we should be able to write G in the form of $B^{-1}A$. However, I cannot seem to be able to find a way to do this. Is there, in fact, a way to rewrite this expression in this way? Or do I have some flawed reasoning somewhere in the above statements?

First, optimizing $\frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x}$ is not the same as optimizing $\frac{x^T B^{-1}A x}{x^T x}$. For a specific example, consider
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
,
\quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
The generalized eigenvalues of $(A, B)$ are $\frac{1}{3}$ and $1$, while the only eigenvalue of $B^{-1}A$ is $\frac{2}{3}$ (computed using this python code).

To rewrite $\frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x}$ as $\frac{y^T G y}{y^T y}$ (I've deliberately renamed the vector variable, because we're optimizing wrt it), you'd have to decompose $B$ as a product of the form $L^T L$ (for example, using the Cholesky decomposition), and then write
$$x^T B x = x^T L^T L x = (Lx)^T Lx$$
Now set $y = Lx$ and $x = L^{-1}y$ to get
$$\frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} = \frac{(L^{-1}y)^T A (L^{-1}y)}{(Lx)^T (Lx)} = \frac{y^T (L^{-T} A L^{-1}) y}{y^T y} = \frac{y^T G y}{y^T y}$$
with
$$G = L^{-T} A L^{-1}$$
In geometric terms, we've effectively switched to a basis where the quadratic form in the denominator $x^T B x$ turns into the standard Euclidean norm $x^T x$, with $L$ being the coordinate change matrix.
We can assume the matrices $B$ and $L$ are invertible, otherwise the original optimization problem is ill-posed.
If $B$ isn't symmetric, you can replace it with its symmetrization $B_S = \frac{B+B^T}{2}$, because it represents to the same quadratic form
$$x^T B_S x = x^T B x$$
